# What is the enum for - (minus/underscore) and = (equal/plus) key in Keys enumeration?

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't seem to find them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=VS.80).aspx).

I'm trying to get them include in my hotkey selection dialog.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Checkout `Oem*`, from the link that you provided:

```
OemMinus    The OEM minus key on any country/region keyboard (Windows 2000 or later). 
Oemplus     The OEM plus key on any country/region keyboard (Windows 2000 or later).
```

You can have something like:

```
if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.OemMinus) ) ZoomOutOrSomething();//
```

Comment: You can also use Key.Add and Key.Subtract to indicate the Plus and the Minus key in the numpad.

Comment: Strangely, `OemMinus` has an **uppercase** `M`, yet `Oemplus` has a **lowercase** `p`.    Beware `Oemcomma` and `Oemtilde` are also weirdly lowercase.  All the other `Oem*` keys are uppercase.   It's true, just don't ask me why!  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4):

Would OemMinus and OemPlus work for you?